# vue-for and vue-if running out of memory when rendering large data object

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am not very experienced with frontend development, but I have been creating a results page to display search results of GitHub repositories matched to keywords. Each GitHub repository will have its own div panel and the number of those panels could be anywhere from 1-100,000. I've been using a Vue app which first makes a `XMLHttpRequest` to our backend to get a large array of repository objects. I have a `vue-if` on the main page container to prevent rendering any of the repository divs until the data has loaded. On the repository div I have a `v-for` to create a panel for every returned repository.

When the page does go to display ~5,000 repositories it become unresponsive and nothing is shown on the page. After some time it will eventually display that there has been a memory exception: `SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED`.

**Container v-if**

```
<div id="page-container" v-if="!loading">
```

**Div v-for**

```
<div id="result" v-for="repo in repositories">
  <p><b> Repository Name: </b></p><p> {{repo.items.name}} </p><br>
```

**Vue App**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#page-container',
    data: {
        total_num: 0,
        num_new: 0,
        loading: true,
        repositories: [],
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
    },
    methods: {
        getRepositories() {
            var vm = this;
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/repository?search_term=xxxxx";
            Http.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            Http.open('GET', url);
            Http.send();
            Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                vm.repositories = Http.responseText;
                vm.loading = false;
                console.log(vm.repositories);
            };
        },
    }
})
app.getRepositories();
```

I have heard of vuex, and also heard that react is really good with handling large amounts of data but would ideally like to stick with vue. I'm also not using any npm management or other library manager and am just using CDNs. Any suggestions on how to best achieve this goal would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

It's more than just the one p line we are displaying in the result. Below is the full repository object and correspoing div. Not all {{}} references are in place for testing.

```
{
  "model": "salt.repository",
  "pk": 4652,
  "fields": {
    "title": "fsanli23/JavaProgramming2020_B21",
    "url": "https://github.com/fsanli23/JavaProgramming2020_B21",
    "num_search_terms": 1,
    "detection_date": "2021-10-26T16:24:55.447Z",
    "assigned_user": null,
    "status": "PR"
  }
}
```

```
<div id="result" v-for="repo in repositories">
  <p><b> Repository Name: </b></p><p> {{repo.items.name}} </p><br>
  <p><b> Date Detected: </b></p><p style=" position: relative; left: 24px;"> 09/13/2021 </p><br>
  <p><b> Status: </b></p><p style=" position: relative; left: 77px;"> Pending  Review </p>
  <button id="update" v-on:click="printStuff()" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button> <br>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <p><b> Suspect File Paths: </b></p><br>
    <a id="filepath" href="https://github.com/evinosheaforward/text_sum/blob/7a1cd5584cb8a24db0035ef41e89c85324c5bef7/20_newsgroups/talk.politics.guns/53326"></a>
    <a id="filepath" href="https://github.com/hemanth415/ssdi-uncc-university-selection/blob/5d6439470f03daea2ec3dfcf3ed9932e8bd36bac/branches/Sprint-1/src/com/test/BankerRegistrationTest.java"></a>
    <br>
    <p><b> Assigned to: </b></p><p style="position: relative; left: 42px;"> Jeffery Zuckerburg </p>
    <p style="position: relative; left: 100px;"> <b> Assigned by: </b></p><p style="position: relative; left: 110px;"> Logan Michalak </p>
    <a href="" role="button" style="position: relative; left: 170px;"> Update </a>
  </div>
  <a class="collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" style="float: right;" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <span class="if-collapsed"> Expand </span>
    <span class="if-not-collapsed"> Collapse </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: React isn't good at handling large amounts of data, devs are. For starters, move presentation code that uses data to separate components. You may want to disable reactivity in nested objects because they aren't changed, see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods . It's treated differently in Vue 3. Consider filtering out unused data before assigning it to a component.

Comment: You could avoid printing 5000 objects to the DOM by using a virtual scroller to only display what needs to be displayed as a starter. [Here's one that accomplishes that](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller).

Comment: I suspect that you've written here would work without issue.  5000 lines is nothing.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: I have updated the post with the full code of the object and div we are repeating

Comment: RESOLVED: I was trying to display the v-for on a string data type instead of an object data type. I was missing a line `vm.repositories = JSON.parse(vm.repositories);` in the vue app. Now everything loads and displays properly!